# How to check if number is a Mersenne prime?

Tags: c#, primes

What is an efficient way to check if a `Int32` n is a Mersenne prime?
This is my attempt :

Apparently this code returns true for some numbers which are a Mersenne prime e.g. 31 but it doesn't for others such as 127.
Can somebody tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if a nubmer is a mersenne prime
/// </summary>
/// <param name="candidate"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsMersennePrime(uint n)
{    
    var x = Math.Pow(2, n) - 1;
    return IsPrime((uint)x);
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks if a nubmer is a prime
/// </summary>
/// <param name="candidate"></param>
/// <returns>true if number is a prime false if its not a prime</returns>
private static bool IsPrime(uint candidate)
{
    //
    // Test whether the parameter is a prime number.
    //
    if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
    {
        if (candidate == 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    int num = (int)Math.Sqrt((double)candidate);
    for (int i = 3; i <= num; i += 2)
    {
        if ((candidate % i) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger and stepping through the logic?

Comment: Did you try `IsMersennePrime(5)` and `IsMersennePrime(7)` respectively? Or `IsMersennePrime(31)` and `IsMersennePrime(127)`?

Comment: @Arnauld that Check IsMersennePrime(127) returns false..

Comment: `IsMersennePrime(127)` is actually computing `2^127 - 1` which doesn't fit in an unsigned 32-bit integer. `IsMersennePrime(7)` is computing `2^7 - 1 = 127` (which is the 4th Mersenne prime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want Mersenne primes which fits into an `uint` the best way is to check against actual values. Read more about [A000043](https://oeis.org/A000043) and [A000668](https://oeis.org/A000668).

```
private static int[] A000043 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203, 2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689, 9941, 11213, 19937, 21701, 23209, 44497, 86243, 110503, 132049, 216091, 756839, 859433, 1257787, 1398269, 2976221, 3021377, 6972593, 13466917, 20996011, 24036583, 25964951, 30402457, 32582657 };
private static int[] A000668 = new int[] { 3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287, 2147483647 };

public static bool IsInA000668(int value) => A000668.Contains(value);
public static bool IsInA000043(int value) => A000043.Contains(value);
```